# Can you disable apache logs for a single site using htaccess or in the Virtual Host settings?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, logging

I'm working on a web site where the client doesn't want ANY logging on the site for privacy reasons. The site will be hosted on the same Apache Web Server as a number of other websites which is why I can just turn logging off in Apache. Is there some way to disable logging for an individual site using htaccess rules or by adding something to the VirtualHost settings?

Answer (score 7):

The options seem to be

1. Sending to /dev/null on *nix or C:/nul on Windows ([see here](http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=3184))
2. Removing the base logging directives and duplicating them in each vhost (so there is no logging on for vhosts by default)

Seems like there should be some better way to do this, but that's what I've found.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just comment out (using a '#') the ErrorLog and CustomLog entries in the httpd conf for your virtual host.

http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-disable-and-turn-off-apache-httpd-access-and-error-log/

Comment: That works for disabling logging for the entire web server, which will work, BUT I was hoping to be able to do it on a site by site basis.

Answer (score 0):

I achieve this by making the logging dependent on a non-existing environment variable. So in the `VirtualHost` you can have:

```
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/my_access_log combined env=DISABLED
```

and so long as there is no environment variable called `DISABLED` then you'll get no logs.

I actually arrived here looking for a neater solution but this works without having to change the global `httpd.conf`.

Edit: removed reference to `.htaccess` because `CustomLog` only applies in the global config or in the virtual host config as pointed out by @Basj

Comment: More info in the "conditional logging" section, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html

Comment: This does not seem to work from `.htacess`, only from global config or VirtualHost: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog